# javascript injection on a form to send a post request

Tags: javascript, javascript-injection

well as title suggests, how could I do a `javascript injection` on a `form` to send a `post request`.

I'm pretty new to `JavaScript injections`. I've done different type of injections, but when it comes to `form` it seems google is out of options (or rather I don't know how to do the search)

supposedly this is the form:;

```
<form action="/" method="post">
<h3>enter name to be echoed:</h3>
<input id="myname" name="myname" type="text" value="nafas">
<input type="image" src="/img/funny.png" alt="Echo Name" onclick="progress(true)">
<scripttype="text/javascript">document.write('<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById(\'myname\').value=\'\';return false">Clean</'+'a>')</script>
</form>
```

method `progress` is:

```
function progress(s){
    var o=document.getElementById("myname");
    if(o){
        if(s){
            o.style.backgroundImage="url(/img/progress.gif)"
            o.style.backgroundPosition="right center";
            o.style.backgroundRepeat="no-repeat";
        }else{
            o.style.backgroundImage="none";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "javascript injection". Who is injecting something, how, and where?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to make the form submit itself, get a reference to the form and use the `.submit()` method.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp

If your question involves someone trying to do something evil, they would write an `.onsubmit` method for the form that uses ajax to send data elsewhere.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onsubmit.asp

Also it looks like you might have an error here `<scripttype`